# Ionic Application using Cordova working in iOS Simulator but not on real device

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Angular-flavour Ionic application that is building correctly, launching and logging `Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 724 ms` in an iOS Simulator, but not when launched to an actual device.

With the actual device the log indicates:

```
2020-03-24 19:29:27.273814+0200 MyApp[945:187467] ERROR: Plugin 'IonicCordovaCommon' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2020-03-24 19:29:27.273984+0200 MyApp[945:187467] FAILED pluginJSON = ["IonicCordovaCommon90845249","IonicCordovaCommon","getPreferences",[]]
```

Up to that point the logs are identical.

I've tried to remove all the plugins (`cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-name --force`) and adding them again.

And I can't find any references to `IonicCordovaCommon` in my codebase or in config.xml as the error suggests (edited)

Comment: Not a whole lot people could get from this. You need to provide a sample app or some code that people could inspect.

Comment: Try remove the Platform via `ionic cordova platform remove ios` and then rebuild the App